# Duplicate DNS Configuration Locations

Tags: dns, cpanel, dns-servers

We are having DNS issues.  Pages work, then they don't, or work from one location/network and not from another.  There are multiple locations where DNS records can be set, and we don't know which one is or should be authoritative.  The records are different in each location.

Here is the Arvixe WebsitePanel:

[image: Arvixe]

Here are the settings in the Advanced Zone Editor of cPanel:

[image: cPanel]

The ip addresses are different in each location, but does that even matter?  Which one is actually in control?

The domain is through 1and1, the VPS server is with Arvixe.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You domain is using the following nameservers which you have set at the registrar (1&1):

```
ns1.allmaint.arvixevps.com
ns1.allmaint.arvixevps.com
```

Therefore the domain is using the Arvixe DNS. So out of the two pictures you have shown the top one is the DNS records actually being used and the one in control.

The settings in cPanel have no effect at all because the domain is not pointed to the cPanel nameservers. If you changed the nameserver at the domain registrar (1&1 in your case) to your cPanel nameservers then the cPanel DNS would be used.

cPanel has a build in DNS and by default is expecting users to use it. For ease of use to the user if they were to use the cPanel DNS it will auto create records for any new domains you add or sub domains; while in your case you will have to manage your records at the registrar.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple domains registered at multiple registrars but all are hosted elsewhere (Different Hosting Provider).

You have to use the DNS/Mail Servers provided by the hosting provider (and set them at the Registrar UI); Not the ones provided by the Registrar unless your Registrar and Hosting Provider are the same.

When I pinged your domain name a few seconds ago, I got this IP: 184.168.190.116.

Host Info for alliancemaintenance.com
alliancemaintenance.com has address 184.168.190.116
alliancemaintenance.com mail is handled by 10 mx00.1and1.com.
alliancemaintenance.com mail is handled by 21 mx01.1and1.com.

Ping of ns1.allmaint.arvixevps.com gives this IP: 23.91.72.237 which matches the one in the first picture.

Hope this helps/confirms.